# Swing- close whole application when a dialog is cancelled

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog, java-6

I have a JFrame which on instantiation calls a custom JDialog(Login).
If login is successful i want that jFrame to be visible. And if user presses escape/cancel on that login dialog the whole application should be closed.

How can i do so...

Currently if i dispose dialog the jFrame gets visible.

Comment: Might as well just call `System.exit(-1);`

Comment: Why don't you make the application to show the login dialog only first and if it is successfully logged in initiate the JFrame ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have access to your `JFrame` via a `frame` variable, you can simply call:

```
frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
```

It is probably better than calling a `System.exit()` as it will enable you to run some cleanup code if you have registered a window closing listener to your frame.

Answer (score 3):

You can override the dialog close event :

```
dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

dialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {  
    //Release you source, close all your frames or call a brutal System.exit(0);
  }
});
```